# How to remember authorization when parsing a site on nodejs cookies

Tags: node.js, nightmare

i go to the site and look for an authorization form, if I find it, then I log in, if not, then I do the actions I need

```
let cookie_ = fs.readFileSync("cookies.json");//I am looking for a file with saved cookies
cookie = JSON.parse(cookie_);//Converting to json

nightmare
.goto('https://site.ru/login')//I go to the site
.cookies.set(cookie)//I substitute cookies from the file
.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector('input[id="email"]');//I am looking for a field to enter mail
})
.then(function (page) {
    if(page) {//I check if there is a field for entering mail
        f().then(function (cookies) {//We get the result from the function
            require('fs').writeFileSync(//And write to file
                'cookies.json',
                JSON.stringify(cookies)
            );
        })

    } else {
        console.log('You are logged in');
    }
})
async function f() {//I call the function if we are not authorized
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            nightmare
                .goto('https://site.ru/login')
                .type('input[id="email"]', 'login')//Enter mail
                .type('input[id="password"]', 'passord')//Enter your password
                .click('.btn.btn-danger')//Click on the authorization button
                .wait(2000)//We wait 2 seconds
                .cookies.get()//We receive cookies
                .then(resolve)

        });
    }
```

The file is created, cookies are written, but with the next attempts to run the script, the authorization form still appears

I also tried first to go to - `goto('about: blank')` then set `cookies` and then go to `goto('https://site.ru/login')`
Error - `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Setting cookie failed`

Comment: You're calling `.goto('https://site.ru/login')` and *then* you're calling `.cookies.set(...)`. Wouldn't it be logical that you set cookies first and then navigate to the site?

Comment: If I install cookies and then go to the site, I get the error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Setting cookie failed.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in nightmare, but my point remains valid. A logon cookie works by being sent *as part of the initial request*. You can't load a site and then set cookies, that's just not how HTTP works. if you're researching this issue, you should research it with this in mind.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks, I will study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it was not possible to solve the problem through `nightmare`
Solved with `puppeteer`

Example - saving cookies to file

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('https://github.com/login')

  await page.type('#login_field', process.env.GITHUB_USER)
  await page.type('#password', process.env.GITHUB_PWD)

  await page.waitForSelector('.js-cookie-consent-reject')
  await page.click('.js-cookie-consent-reject')
  await page.$eval('[name="commit"]', (elem) => elem.click())
  await page.waitForNavigation()

  const cookies = await page.cookies()
  const cookieJson = JSON.stringify(cookies)

  fs.writeFileSync('cookies.json', cookieJson)

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Reading cookies from a file

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  const cookies = fs.readFileSync('cookies.json', 'utf8')

  const deserializedCookies = JSON.parse(cookies)
  await page.setCookie(...deserializedCookies)

  await page.goto(`https://github.com/${process.env.GITHUB_USER}`)

  await browser.close()
})()
```

[Article](https://www.checklyhq.com/learn/headless/managing-cookies/)